# Regex, positive or negative int not preceding by 0 or minus

Tags: regex, zero, negative-number

I want to create a filter which checks if typed value is expected.
Allowed are negative and positive (without '+' sugn) numbers not preceding by zero. Also negative sign itself is allowed.
Problem is I can do search of negative number but I don't know how to add condition to find also minus.
I've tried to use lookaheads and whole this mechanism, but I've failed.
OK: -, -10, -54, 66, 0, 1
NOK: +, +1, -010, 010

Comment: Show us the regex(es) you have tried.

Comment: Also, why is just `-` OK? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CinCout, because if I want to type negative number I need to start from "-" and I want to have "one stage" comparision. What is the point of showing non-working regexp?

Comment: When you list your efforts, the community knows that you have tried something on your own and not just blatantly asking us to write something for you (which is off-topic on SO). That also helps the community to know your understanding of the topic/concept(s) and thus provide you an answer which will definitely be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
^(?:(?:-?(?:[1-9]\d*)?)|0)$
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CY2laj/4/)

Explanation:

```
^ start marker
- literally matches - sign
? makes it optional
([1-9]\d*) start by non zero digit followed by optional digits
([1-9]\d*)? the question sign makes it optional
|0 means or a single zero
$ end marker
```

Comment: a single 0 doesn't match though.

Comment: @Wli wow great catch ... definitely misseed due to hurry ! thanks

Comment: Yes, thats it. When I look at this, I think this regexp is far beyond my skills.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct working regex :

```
^-?(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?$
```

It will cover all the test cases

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
`^-?(?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0))?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W2hKVP/1)

Start with an optional `-`, then make sure the first digit is anything but 0 with the rest being as many digits as possible. Also handle the special case of `0` only.